# When did the spice box get it's classical shape?

Tags: history, havdalah, smell, geometry-shapes

All Havdala Bsamamim boxes I have ever seen are in the shape of a [tower](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Havdalah.jpg/386px-Havdalah.jpg).

Why (and when) did it take on that classical shape (rather than just a silver box)?

Comment: *All*? They come in all sorts of shapes. I myself use one shaped like a rose.

Comment: What about the once-common fish-shaped besamim box ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](http://jhom.com/topics/spices/tower.html), by Rabbi Shubert Spero, says that the fashion started around the sixteenth century.

He suggests that a tower symbolizes strength and security, and so it fits well with Havdalah, in which we speak of Hashem as our source of security ("כי עזי וזמרת י-ה"), and also that it is associated with the rebuilding of the Beis Hamikdash and the coming of Eliyahu and Moshiach, a major theme of Motzaei Shabbos.

Answer (score 0):

Spices tended to be expensive. Expensive things were kept in a vault, often located in a high tower (if one owned a castle...).
The day-to-day experience of Medieval Jews made those towers a natural model for b'samim.